# JSON data / square bracket stripping

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

Was working on a way to combine the data from multiple data sources via async.map. However I have an issue with the new data structure thats a result of combining the multiple documents into one...  Extra brackets around each record.

This is what my normal json document is formatted like:

```
 {
 "_id": "527b16584930484431f054be",
 "caption": "lucky",
 "created_time": "1383652572",
 "full_name": "kkelcie",
 },
{
"_id": "527b16584930484431f054bd",
"caption": "Me with all my friends on our day off work. ",
"created_time": "1383798277",
"full_name": "zeftodeathbitch"
}
```

And here is he way my new data from multiple queries is formatting:

```
[
 {
  "_id": "52799ef14930484431ed58ed",
  "caption": "☀",
  "created_time": "1383698900",
  "full_name": "andreSDFFSdfazapata"
 }
],
[
 {
  "_id": "5279a7514930484431ed6b2f",
  "caption": "Clear Lake",
  "created_time": "1375497332",
  "full_name": "SCALLSDFFYSWAG"
  }
]
```

So.... How can strip out the square brackes around each specific record??  Nothing working on it now :)

Comment: You should add the code, that creates this result ...

Comment: Show us the code were you use `async.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19887995/893780), you might want to rewrite your query:

```
async.map(arLimit, function(eachrecord, callback){

  UGC_DB_Model.findOne().skip(eachrecord).limit(-1).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback(null, result);
    }
  });

}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log("(it's empty): " + result); 
});
```

This uses `findOne` instead of `find`; `findOne` will always return (at most) one result, whereas `find` will return multiple (as an array). But because you're limiting your results to one anyway, `findOne` is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks, sure, this makes more sense - but doesn't change the issue that each result is wrapped with [],  instead of [{},{},{}] I have [{}],[{}],{{}] etc.  I don't think that can be altered, so how would I strip it?

Comment: think my issue goes back to not understanding why async.map works... I don't understand how the "result" data is aggregated from each of the queries that are executed.  That would help me understand why I have a collection of arrays.... as well as how to force it to not be...?

Comment: @chuckjones242 `map` takes the result passed to the `callback` function and adds it to an array. If `result` is an array itself, you'll get arrays-in-arrays; if `result` is an object (as it should when you use `findOne`), you get an array-of-objects. You shouldn't be getting `[ [{}],[{}],[{}] ]` with my example.